# Actual value falling within prediction interval rather than predicted value falling within actual value range?

Tags: probability, prediction

I'm trying to predict a price for an item on the website. I'm interested in classifying the prediction as good or bad. There are two approaches that I can think of, and I'm wondering which one is better and why:

1. See what percent of the time the predicted value falls within a certain distance away from the actual value. If it falls within a certain interval of the actual value, classify this as good.
2. See what percent of the time the actual values fall within a prediction interval of the predicted value. If the actual value falls within the prediction interval, classify as good.

Let $in$ be the event that the actual value falls within the prediction interval. The prediction interval is defined as $\hat{\mu} \pm x*\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}$ where $\hat{\mu}$ is the predicted value, $\sigma$ is the variance of the sample, and n is the number of observations. $x$ is a value chosen to represent the level of desired certainty. Let A represent the actual value:

$P(in)=P(\hat{\mu} - x*\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}} <  A  < \hat{\mu} + x*\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})$

Which is the correct approach, and why?

---

*Note: I have since realized that I may have incorrectly termed the interval displayed above a prediction interval when in fact it is a confidence interval. What I would like to use is the prediction interval...still reading up to understand the difference between these intervals.